# split csv according to field in Java

Tags: java, linux, csv, split

I want to split a csv file according to the last "field".
For instance the csv file contains:

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,1
```

The numbers indicate categories.

This file should be split into seperate files according to the numbers (resp. categories) so that there exist three files.

first file:

```
a,1
d,1
```

second file:

```
b,2
```

third file:

```
c,3
```

The greedy method would be to read the csv per line, split the string at "," and seperate the last element (here the number). Afterwards I could check the number of the current line and put it into a FileWriter.
But: I do not know how many categories there will be as I want to keep the system extensible. Therefore the number of needed FileWriters is unknown.

As an alternative I could read the complete csv file for each category. In the first iteration only lines of category "1" would be processed and written into "1.csv", in the second step only lines of category "2" go into "2.csv" and so on.
But: This means the file has to be read as many times as categories exist which could be quite often.

Do you know whether there is an elegant solution for this purpose?

I also appreciate linux-based solutions! Maybe it is not necessary to create a Java program?
I guess that awk could be the tool of choice?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a more generic way. In this case I don't need to know all the items in the second column, so this is automatic:

`total.csv`:

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,1
```

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat total.csv)          
do          
   filename=$(echo $line | awk -F "," '{print $2}')
   echo $line >> $filename.csv 
done
```

outputs: 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv

Comment: Just for completeness: For some reason this does not work if there are whitespaces in the csv "fields". For instance a line containing dates like "2013-08-19 00:24:27,2013-08-19 00:24:52,a,1" gets split and written to "1.csv" only like this: "00:24:52,a,1". The first part from the beginning to the last whitespace in that line gets dropped. I do not know why this is but I will work on that and post my findings here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `awk` one-liner:

```
awk -F, '{print >> "output"$NF".csv"}' input.csv
```

It will read each line and write it to the appropriate output csv file, based on the value of the last field of the line.